# AlertDialog multiplechoice and other dialogs

Tags: android

I am trying to do an alert dialog with multiple choice it compiles without errors but when i click the button stop the program. All the rest buttons work i am using two clases for the same layout that have buttons. The complete package is in this onedrive
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtHUK0teCx0SENyMf?e=EPTpoR
Or this:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtGOqDkoMq20A-hbc?e=l1J2Nk
(This is the folder for futures updates.)
package com.sistemariego;
    import 
    android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
     import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

```
import android.widget.ListView;  
import android.widget.TextView;  
import java.lang.StringBuilder;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
 import android.widget.Button;  
import com.sistemariego.R; 
import java.util.Calendar; 
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.AlertDialog;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.DialogInterface;  
public class SoleTiempo2 extends Activity{  

private Context context = this;  
public static int diasselected=0;      
public static int setdias=0;  
private static boolean [] 
 arrayCkDias =   {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false};  
AlertDialog alertDialog;  
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){  
super onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView (R.layout.datos_tiempo);  
Button dias2 = findViewById(R.id.dias);  
};  
public void botonClickdias(){  
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);  
alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(SoleTiempo.arrayDias,arrayCkDias, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {  
@Override. 
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {  
switch (which) {  
case 0:  
 if(isChecked){  
       for(int i=0; i < 8; i++){  
        arrayCkDias[i]=true;};  
        diasselected = 255;};  
         case 1:    
        setdias=1;    
        if(isChecked){    
            diasselected= 
     diasselected | setdias;}    
        else {    
        diasselected =
        diasselected  & (~setdias);     
    };  
             case 2:    
            setdias=2;  
         if(isChecked) {  
         diasselected=   
diasselected | setdias;}    
        else.  
         {diasselected =
         diasselected  & 
 (~setdias);};  
        case 3:   
      setdias=4;   
       if(isChecked){  
        diasselected= 
      diasselected | setdias;}  
        else{   
    diasselected =  
    diasselected  & (~setdias); };  
    case 4:
    setdias=8;  
    if(isChecked){  
   diasselected =
    diasselected  & (~setdias);}   
    else{    
    diasselected =  
    diasselected  & (~setdias);};  
 case 5: ;
    setdias=16;
    if(isChecked){  
    diasselected = 
    diasselected | setdias;}
    else. 
    {diasselected =
    diasselected  & (~setdias);};  
    case 6:  
    setdias=32;   
    if(isChecked){  
    diasselected= diasselected | setdias; }  
    else{  
    diasselected =  
 diasselected  (~setdias);};  
    case 7:
    setdias=64;
    if(isChecked){
    diasselected= diasselected | setdias;}
    else{  
    diasselected =    
    diasselected  & 
(~setdias);};    
 };  
}  
}); 

 alertDialogBuildeg..setPositiveButton( "Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListenerr() { 
public void  onClick{  
DialogInterface dialog,int id) {  
alertDialog.dismiss(),  
 }  
 });  
  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
public void onClick(  
 DialogInterface dialog,int id) {  
alertDialog.cancel();  
}  
});  
alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();  
alertDialog.show();  
}  
}  
No checked errors.
```

Comment: Ummm, what is the question?

Comment: I cant do this alert dialog dont have checked errors. I cant find the error. I dont know it the array  needs an adapter or for what reason dont work and dont show error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your AlertDialog Code with this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(SoleTiempo.arrayDias, arrayCkDias, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Now is more updated the paclage already unfinished 
 https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtHpxVWfQbhM7yCNr?e=rXoy6X  OR CHECK THE DITECTORY FOR FUTURE UPDATES.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without write the code again that compiles. The problem was that i used a method and the onclick of the arributes of the button. I solved it making a listener for the button and all the code I placed inside of the oncreate override and now work. Anyway i have other isue to solve one option is ALL and have to make checked all the rest. I tried to do it modifying the array of the builder but didnt work. So maybe exist any method to change the check of the listed items. DOES ANYONES KNOWS IF EXIST THIS METHOD OR THE WAY TO CHANGE THE ITEMS INSIDE OF THE LISTENER?

The package solved is here (already the application is unfinished):
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtHbMpKmhPSzgmTjj?e=t44nih

And here the directory for futures updates

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtGOqDkoMq20A-hbc?e=l1J2Nk

Answer (score 0):

I solve alone also the problem of use une check box for all and 7 for the days of the week. I used AbsListView and a couple of IF

```
final AbsListView listDias =  (AbsListView) alertDialog.getListView();
```

AND THEN THIS IS THE IF

```
if (((diasselected/128)==1) & (which>0) & (!(isChecked))){  
 setdias=128;  
 diasselected = diasselected  & (~setdias);  
 arrayCkDias[0]=false;  


listDias.setItemChecked(0,false);
```

The complete package is here

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtHccP3GUaBsrs7dx?e=VWCbnN

Or in this directory in furure changes:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asr3Ewn45KOLtGOqDkoMq20A-hbc?e=l1J2Nk